# How to send Chat Invitation, to GTalk using PHP?

Tags: php, gmail, chat

I want to send Chat Invitation to multiple users of Gmail, from my database list. How can it be done using PHP?
example: My data table contains some list of email address(i.e abc@gmail.com, def@gmail.com....), and i want to send all these email address an invitation from my end(i.e me@gmail.com or me@jabber.com)

Comment: what exactly is your question? Does the chat invitation have a specific format, or are you asking how to mail things?

Comment: actually i want to send only Chat invitation to send IM, and not to send bulk mails..like example in gmail we send a chat invitation through chat box, and then the person accepts it so that we can chat.

Answer (score 0):

You will want to take a look at this I believe, I've had it in my scrap book of things to play with for awhile so I can't offer much more advice than that.

http://code.google.com/p/xmpphp/

Comment: i have tried this but giving me error..is it any change i have to do in server settings??
the error is as follows..
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'XMPPHP_Exception' with message 'Could not connect before timeout.' in /home/msconslt/public_html/vforms/XMPPHP/XMLStream.php:327 Stack trace: #0 /home/msconslt/public_html/vforms/message.php(4): XMPPHP_XMLStream->connect() #1 {main} thrown in /home/msconslt/public_html/vforms/XMPPHP/XMLStream.php  on line 327

Comment: Well unfortunately I've never used it before as I said but if I had to guess from looking at the 'Could not connect before timeout' error your connection settings might be incorrect.  If I get a chance this weekend I'll play with it some and see.

Comment: same problem here, hope someone can solve the connect problem